# Wrong query in SQL when passing variables through $_GET

Tags: php, sql

Here is the query:

```
$table = $_GET['type'];
$q="DELETE FROM '$table' WHERE cont_id='".$_GET['where']."'";
```

I also tried removing the single/double quotes on the `$_GET` part, but didn't work. I'm printing the values of my variables before executing the query and they are right so I don't think that's the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code is very vulnerable to injection. You should switch to using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database table names should not be enclosed with single quotes.

Corrected SQL:

```
$q="DELETE FROM $table WHERE cont_id='".$_GET['where']."'";
```

Tables and field names can be enclosed with backticks (`) to avoid clashes with

[MySQL reserved keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html).

In that case, corrected SQL should be:

```
$q="DELETE FROM `$table` WHERE `cont_id` = '".$_GET['where']."'";
```

Also, do not trust input from user.

This can cause security vulnerability.

use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for `$_GET['where']`

Comment: It's good practice to enclose variables with single quotes `'` and table names with backticks `\``

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! I was confused with the backticks and single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

In you want quote table name you had to use symbol "`"

```
$table = $_GET['type'];
$q="DELETE FROM `$table` WHERE cont_id='".$_GET['where']."'";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$table = $_GET['type'];
$q="DELETE FROM $table WHERE cont_id='".$_GET['where']."'";
```

OR

```
$table = $_GET['type'];
$q="DELETE FROM `$table` WHERE cont_id='".$_GET['where']."'";
```